# Power Query replace nulls with partial text of another column

Tags: excel, powerquery

(New to Power Query) I have Vendor column with some values and with some nulls.  I'd like to populate the nulls with some starting text from another column (Memo/Description, but not the entire field, just the first word).  I'm essentially trying to combine the Replace Values with the Text.BeforeDelimiter, but I don't know the syntax all that well.  Here's what I'm trying:

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Sorted Rows",
null,
each Text.BeforeDelimiter([#"Memo/Description"], " "),
Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Vendor"})

There was no error with this formula, but it didn't make the necessary changes.

I cobbled this together by first trying out Add Column based on the first word, and that formula had an argument at the very end for type text.  Not sure if that needs to be in this formula also, and if so, do I put parentheses around what?

Comment: Looks like you have to use `Replacer.ReplaceValue` with nulls.

Comment: Yay!  Thank you!!